# Unblock synchronous read on boost::asio::serial_port

Tags: c++, windows, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I have a `boost::thread` which performs synchronous reads on a `boost::asio::serial_port`. When I destroy an instance of the class which contains both, I want the thread to end gracefully even if its blocked in a read call. How can I do this?

Looking at the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html), I tried `cancel`, but it works only for asynchronous reads/writes. Then I tried `close`, but I got an exception and it wasn't the kind you can recover from. Perhaps using `send_break` or `native_handle`? (this is Windows and portability's not critical)

**Update**: I also tried to `stop` the `io_service` I passed to the serial port object's constructor, but the `read` wasn't unblocked.

**Edit**: The exception is actually "catchable", but I'd hate to put a try/catch block inside a destructor, and refactoring the code to do the shutdown process outside the destructor would trigger lots of changes in upper layers. So I'd only go for this solution if some Boost authority says there is no other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to unblock the synchronous read as you ask to.

There are two options:

- `close`/`shutdown` the port and catch an exception, which was raised
- use asynchronous reads and `cancel` them, when you shutdown your application

The first one, of course, is not a good idea, because you cannot distinguish terminating application from error.

Comment: And that's why Boost::Asio isn't called Boost::SioAndAsio :)

Comment: You mean boost::asio::serial_port is not meant to be read or written synchronously? I went for synchronous read/write to avoid polling... If they allow me to read and write that way, which works wonderfully and doesn't waste CPU cycles, they should offer a way to end gracefully.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do the same a few days ago.

Comment: Did you ask at the Boost mailing lists and were told there was no other way?

Comment: No, but I've found some pointers, and read most of the asio documentation. Look, at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856957/interrupt-boostasio-synchronous-read

Comment: I read that question, but disregarded the answers because they were using a TCP socket, not a serial port. I'll read it in more detail and see if I can apply something.

Answer (score 1):

On close, you say that you get an exception that 'wasn't the kind you can recover from'.

What does this mean?

The solution seems to be to catch the exception.  Why cannot you do that?

For the case when you want to distinguish between an error and program termination, set a flag on program termination before the close.  In the exception handler ( catch )  check the flag.  If set, handle as program termination, else handle as error.

You say that you do not wish to place a try/catch block inside a destructor.  This seems like an odd prejudice to me, but OK there are other ways.

1. You can allow the exception to propagate all the way to the topmost catch block that surrounds all your code, and handle it there.  ( You do have such a try/catch block protecting your entire application, of course :-)
2. Other ways are also possible ... but boss just dropped by

Comment: I actually ignored the exception and hit continue in the debugger, but since it happened inside a destructor, it irked me too much too put a try/catch block there. I could refactor my code to do this outside the destructor, but this would ripple up many layers of destructors calls and would be pretty bothersome. I would only accept this as a last resort solution. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: About exceptions in destructors, [there are pitfalls](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9). But I think that the dangerous scenario mentioned in the faq does not apply. Besides, I asked at the boost-users mail list and they told me to catch `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`, which allows me to distinguish shutdown from error, I believe. I'll try this out and if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I tried to catch `std::exception` and ran into Runtime Check Failure #0 (the value of ESP was not preserved or something like that). I gave up and decided to use async_read and write + Boost Windows event equivalent to perform blocking reads and writes.