# Issue with Boost Sockets

Tags: c++, boost-asio

First of all I would like to state that I am a beginner at C++ and boost in general, although I do have some experience with languages such as Java and C#.

That being said, I am having a problem when transferring data through Boost TCP sockets. I am using this code:

To Send:

```
tcp::socket s(io_service);
        boost::asio::connect(s, iterator);
        string response = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg1) )->str() 
            + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg2) )->str()
            + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg3) )->str()
            + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg4) )->str()
            + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg5) )->str()
            + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg6) )->str();

        //pad the rest
        while (response.length() < max_length)
        {
            response += ' ';
        }
        boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(response, sizeof(response)));
```

To Read:

```
tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
    while(true)
    {
        socket_ptr sock(new tcp::socket(io_service));
        a.accept(*sock);
        boost::thread t(boost::bind(session, sock));
    }
...
void session(socket_ptr sock)
{
    char data[max_length];
    size_t length;
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {           
            boost::system::error_code error;
            //size_t length = sock->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), error);
            length = boost::asio::read(*sock, boost::asio::buffer(data, sizeof data));
            std::cout << "Length " << length << endl;
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
            }
            else if (error)
            {
                throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
            }

        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << data << endl;  
        string message = e.what();
        if(std::string::npos != message.find(END_OF_FILE))
        {
            domeSomethingWithTheData(data); 
            memset(data, 0, sizeof data);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << data <<endl;
            std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What I cannot understand is that, regardless of what I use, (either `boost::asio::read` or `sock->read_some`), I never get more than 32 characters worth of data. I have tried increasing the size of the buffer to `2048`, but the issue persisted.

The buffer always contains more than 32 characters (most of which are garbage) but I am assuming that these are not actually being sent from the client but rather come from the actual allocation of the buffer on the server side since `std::cout << "Length " << length` prints out 32.

Any information on how I can, from the client, send an arbitrary amount of characters to the server will be appreciated.

EDIT:

After the pointers provided by Rafal Rawicki, I am now using this code:

```
 boost::asio::streambuf buffer;
    boost::asio::read_until(*sock, buffer, '\n');
    std::istream is(&buffer);
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line); 
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
```

The client side remained unchanged with the only exception that I am adding a `\n` at the end. This yields a lot of `End of file` Exceptions however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html) you've used should read data until the buffer is full or an error occured.

`boost::asio::socket::read_some` is supposed to read **some data** from the socket.

To read desired amount of data you can:

- use boost::asio::read as you tried.
- use multiple calls of these functions to read more and more data
- use [`read_until`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until.html) to read data to the expected delimiter
- use this [`boost::asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload3.html) overload, which takes as an argument `completion_condition`, for example, number of bytes.

Also, please look at the [issues with synchronous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9200005/13767) with Boost.Asio and consider using asynchronous operations instead.

EDIT: I've missed incorrect buffer initialization in client code. The use of `boost::asio::read` was correct.

You can't initialize buffer like that:

```
boost::asio::buffer(response, sizeof(response));
```

because `sizeof` returns the size of `std::string` structure, not the whole string. On my machine it's always 8. Use:

```
boost::asio::buffer(response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have read that `read_some` does not guarantee to return all the data, but I did not know the same applied to `read`. I am now trying to use `read_until`. The problem is that it does seem to work however, I am getting a lot of `End of file` Exceptions. Do you have any idea on how I can go past that? I will be updating the code I am now using momentarily.

Comment: @npinti I've linked two reads in my answer to the appropriate overloads in Boost documentation - it applies only to specific overloads of `read`.

Comment: @npinti `boost::asio::buffer(response, sizeof(response)));` - this line is completely wrong, **use: `boost::asio::buffer(response);`**. Sizeof does not return the valid size of the string. `boost::asio::buffer` has an overload for string, if you'd like to do this other way it should be `boost::asio::buffer(response.c_str(), response.size()));`

Comment: Regardless of what I seem to be using, I seem to be either getting what I am passing, if there is less than 32 characters or else, I get an End of file exception with the data being truncated to 32 characters. Maybe there is some flag I need to be setting?

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to have been, as you suggested, this piece here: `boost::asio::buffer(response, sizeof(response));`. It was truncating everything to 32.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not an answer to your question. But a quick word of advice.

Your string concatenation code is cruel!

```
string response = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg1) )->str() 
        + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg2) )->str()
        + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg3) )->str()
        + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg4) )->str()
        + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg5) )->str()
        + "," + static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << arg6) )->str();
```

For each arg you create a new `ostringstream`, write the value to it, then you **unnecessarily** dereference it, then you **unnecessarily** cast it to the type it already has anyway. And finally you use string concatenation to build your final string.

That kind of string concatenation is neither efficient, nor sophisticated at all (requires temporary objects, some wasteful allocations and so on).

`ostringstream` is the right tool for string concatenation and formatting, and it is efficient and sophisticated.

Long story short, your code should rather look like this:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << arg1 << "," << arg2 << "," << arg3 << "," << arg4 << "," << arg5 << "," << arg6;
string response = oss.str();
```